# изучаю python и немогу понять что за

Tags: python

```
 end1 = "C"
 end2 = "h"
 end3 = "e"
 end4 = "e"
 end5 = "s"
 end6 = "e"
 end7 = "B"
 end8 = "u"
 end9 = "r"
 end10 = "g"
 end11 = "e"
 end12 = "r"
```

а в конце получилось слово состоящая из 12 букв

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял в вы делаете принт каждой переменной по отдельность

print(end1, end2, end3, ..... и так далее)

Если Вы хотите получить слово целиком то вам стоит воспользоватся оператор конкатенации строк "+", просто напишите

```
end1 = "C"
end2 = "h"
end3 = "e"
end4 = "e"
end5 = "s"
end6 = "e"
end7 = "B"
end8 = "u"
end9 = "r"
end10 = "g"
end11 = "e"
end12 = "r"
print(end1 + end2 + end3 + end3 + end4 + end5 + end6 + end6 + end7 + end8 + end9 + end10 + end11 +end12)
```